# How to cause table cells to use all screen height in TableLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to Android development. 
I have an activity in which I would like to set a few buttons in two table rows.  but currently they use only a small portion of it 
Here is the XML for the layout for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use android:layout_weight="1" in table row

```
 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
```

see this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffff0000">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#ff00ff00">

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#ff00ff">
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: this did not help.They still don't occupy the entire screen height.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, you also need to set probably for each button layout_height = "0dp" so they will occupy one third of the screen's height if you have 3 rows.

Comment: sorry , but are you want that all three row will fill the screen size not only one ?

Comment: Yes, the length of each button should be one third of the screen size, and the width should also be one third of the screen width.

Comment: give android:layout_weight="1" to all table rows among which you want to divide the screen ........

Comment: Your 2nd attempt is awesome (the one with the green and purple areas)! This is what I need. Can you remove your first attempt from your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Its like this....

1. Either goto the GUI tool to edit the XML properties in Eclipse and set the layout property
   `layout weight to 1`.

   OR goto the XML page, and do the following to the Table row `android:layout_weight="1"` 
   `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: What about the layout_width and layout_height of the layout ? do I need to set them to something else , or keep it as fill_parent?

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content" and android:layout_height="wrap_content" i didnt mention them, thinking its quite obvious that you will implement it... sorry for that